# Receive bluetooth data using Broadcast Receiver

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I'm developing an Android application that must receives bluetooth data from a bracelet.
This is the scenario:

1. The user presses a phisical button on the bracelet
2. The bracelet sends a notification to a paired smartphone with some characters (eg "*!*")
3. The smartphone receives the bluetooth data and shows a notification in the notification-bar with a massege like "The bracialed was clicked at 11.30PM and the character  is "*!*"".

I need that this process works **at any moment**, so, even if the user restarts the smartphone and **does not** open the app, the app must still receive message from the bracelet.

For this reasons I immediately thought at the Android Broadcast Receiver, infact this system works even if the app is not in ram.

Is there a BroadCast Receiver that refrects my needs?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: If you have a working bluetooth receiver code, you can just make your application self-start at boot.

Comment: So, you suggest to use a Service?

Comment: Would be a good implementation IMHO.